# How to create a Web Form in Java with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, web

I'm trying to create a simple webform in Java with Eclipse but I've seen that I have to do New Project --> Web --> Dynamic Project

However, all I see when I click on New Project is the screenshoot below. I don't have the Web option.

I'm using Ubuntu and I've installed Eclipse Standard 4.3.2 (http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/Kepler/SR2)
Should I install a different version? Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers?

[image]

**UPDATE**

This is the printshoot of the error when installing the IDE for Java Developers

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*Eclipse IDE for Java EE* is not a different *version* so much as a different package containing support for developing JSPs, Servlets, and other web artifacts. *Kepler SR2*, though, is a version--a two year old one that's since been superseded by *Mars.2*. So download the Mars.2 version of the *Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers*. The download page at http://download.eclipse.org/ should always have the current supported version.

Comment: So I will be able to see and create New Project --> Web --> Dynamic Project with Mars 2 or should I download Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers ? Thanks

Comment: Yes, with the Mars.2 **version** of the Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers **package**.

Comment: So I downloaded and installed Mars 2 version. When opening for the first time ask me for different options I picked the option for Java Developers but I'm getting an error. See Update of original post for printshoot

Comment: What is this that you've downloaded? It should have been a zip file that you unzip and then just run.